# jquery shopping cart value onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, shopping-cart

I wrote a code for a shopping cart. In that for each change in quantity value (either increasing or decreasing) there should be a change in the price. I tried to implement this for a decreasing price with respect to the quantity. I can change the quantity but I am not able to change the price field because the price still gives me the type of object as I `console.log`. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Below is the code:

product.html

```
            <tr>
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                  <img src="images/cloth_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="h5 text-black">Top Up T-Shirt</h2>
                </td>
                <!-- The price -->
                <td>$49.00</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                      <div class="price"></div>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                  <img src="images/cloth_2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="h5 text-black ">Polo Shirt</h2>
                </td>
                <td>$49.00</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="price">8</div>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="remove btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
              </tr>
```

main.js

```
    <script>
    $('.js-btn-minus').on('click', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val() !=0 && $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val() >0)
            {
                $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) - 1);
                var va = parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val());
                va = (parseInt(va));
                this.a = va;
                console.log(this.a);
                var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price');
                console.log(price.val(parseInt(this.a)));
            } 
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: create jsfiddle.

Comment: So for ex. you have  `$49.00`. Now if you click `+`, you want to increase the price to `$50.00` and if you hit -, you want to decrease the price. Am I right? Or you want something else?

Comment: _“because the price still gives me the type of object as i console.log”_ - you are not logging any actual price value there with `console.log(price.val(parseInt(this.a)))`, you are logging the return value of jQuery’s `val()` method - and that is of course a jQuery object again (because that is the basis for method chaining to work in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

use price.html or price.text instead of price.val and then remember, input get value by .val() but other element get by .html() or .text()

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your `table` is not well structured. Second thing is that your requirement is not exactly clear to me.

Thought I assume you want to increase or decrease the price where the class is `price`.

You are receiving the whole element as you are using `val()` and it is always going to be the object.

If you could tell the exact issue/requirement, I can help you out.

```js
$('.js-btn-minus').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var next_val = parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) - 1;
    if (next_val < 0){
      next_val = 0
      $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(0)
    }
    else{
      $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(next_val);
      var existing_value = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html()
    if ((existing_value || '') == ''){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(next_val)
    }
    else{
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(existing_value - 1)
    }
    }
    
    // Price updates    
    //var current_price = parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').parent().prev('td').html().replace('$', ''))
    //var final_price = current_price - next_val;    
    
});
$('.js-btn-plus').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var next_val = parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) + 1;
    if (next_val < 0){
    next_val=0;
      $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(0)
    }
    else{
      $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(next_val);
      var existing_value = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html())
    if ((existing_value || '') == ''){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(next_val)
    }
    else{
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').html(existing_value + 1)
    }
    }
  // Price updates
    //var current_price = parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').parent().prev('td').html().replace('$', ''))
    //var final_price = current_price + 1
    //console.log(final_price)
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                  <img src="images/cloth_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="h5 text-black">Top Up T-Shirt</h2>
                </td>
                <!-- The price -->
                <td class="current_price">$49.00</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                      <div class="price"></div>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                  <img src="images/cloth_2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="h5 text-black ">Polo Shirt</h2>
                </td>
                <td class="current_price">$49.00</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="price">8</div>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="remove btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
```